# The behaviour of nested comments is broken (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

When the "helpful" or "reply" link is clicked. it closes the previous opened tabs.
I want to create a nesting of comments just like facebook or any discussion page
Here is my code

http://plnkr.co/edit/isWE1w9aGtMCRd8QGzHh?p=preview

The problem of the reply button collapsing is solved

but when reply blockquote is showing many input field.
What can be done so that only when the reply link is clicked it should then open the input tag just like facebook.

```js
var app = angular.module("myDiscuss", []);
app.controller("TabController", function($scope) {
  $scope.tab = null;
  $scope.subTab = null;
  $scope.like = null;
  $scope.subLike = null;

  $scope.selectLike = function(setTab) {
    $scope.like = setTab;
  };
  $scope.selectSubLike = function(setTab) {
    $scope.subLike = setTab;
  }
  $scope.selectTab = function(setTab) {
    $scope.tab = setTab;
  };
  $scope.selectSubTab = function(setTab) {
   $scope.subTab = setTab;
  };
  $scope.isSelected = function(checkTab) {
    return $scope.tab === checkTab;
  };
  $scope.isSelectedSub = function(checkTab) {
    return $scope.subTab === checkTab;
  };
  $scope.isSelectedLike = function(checkTab) {
    return $scope.like === checkTab;
  };
  $scope.isSelectedSubLike = function(checkTab) {
    return $scope.subLike === checkTab;
  }

});
```

Comment: No so sure what's the problem?

Comment: open the link and checkout the html page on clicking on comment it open the input box whenever the comment is posted it is working fine but whenever the sub comment or reply is done to any previous comment it closes the previous section opened. i want that it should not do that.

Comment: Still unclear.  What do you mean "it closes the previous section opened"? What is the "previous section"?   Nothing disappears when I try it...

Comment: ok.
First open the comment tab
then write 2 comments
then in those 2 comments do the reply part multiple times in each
then click either the helpful or reply of any of the sub replies it will closes the other comment with all its replies
on clicking the helpful link it show all the text of that comment section.
I want that it should so only the text of that blockqoute.

Comment: Oh jeez, now I see it.  The behavior of nested comments is broken, this has nothing to do with the "tabs" mentioned in the title or the code pasted into the question.

Comment: actually the ng-click and ng-show function are working with the code shown in the question. For example subLike ,subTab